# How do I get a DASK dataframe into a MySQL datatable?

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I have fetched data from a CSV file, and it is held and manipulated in my Dask dataframe. From there I need to write the data into a data table. I have not really come across any solutions for this. Pandas have built-in functionality for this with its to_sql function, so I am unsure whether I need to convert to Pandas first? I currently think that converting the Dask dataframe to Pandas will cause it to be loaded fully into memory, which may defeat the purpose of using Dask in the first place.

What would the best and fastest approach be to write a Dask dataframe to a datatable?

Comment: May be solved by https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/6038

Answer (score 3):

assuming you have dask dataframe as df, you just need to this this:

```
df.to_sql(table, schema=schema, uri=conn_str, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

i've found this is easily the quickest method for dask dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with @kfk's answer, as I also investigated that, but my solution was as follows.

I drop the DASK dataframe to a csv, and from there pick the CSV up with a Golang application that shoves the data into Mongo using multi-threading. For 4.5 million rows, the speed went from 38 minutes using "load local infile" to 2 minutes using a multi-threaded app.

Answer (score -1):

`pandas.to_sql()` is not the fastest way to load data into a database. `to_sql()` uses the ODBC driver connection which is a lot *slower* than the built in bulk load method.

You can load data from a csv file in MySQL like this:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'some_file.csv'
INTO TABLE some_mysql_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

So what I would do is this:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#1) create a csv file
df = dd.read_csv('2014-*.csv')
df.to_csv("some_file.csv")

#2) load the file
sql = """LOAD DATA INFILE 'some_file.csv' 
         INTO TABLE some_mysql_table
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';"""

engine = create_engine("mysql://user:password@server")
engine.execute(sql)
```

You wrap the above into a function easily and use it instead of `to_sql`.